# Connection refused when running "solr create"

Tags: solr, solr8

I'm trying to automate the creation of new collections using the `solr create` command in Solr 8.11.1 as follows

`sudo -u solr /opt/solr/bin/solr create -c collection_name`

However, I get connection refused since Solr is listening on the host IP address, not `localhost`

`ERROR: Connect to localhost:8983 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

Is there a way to specify a hostname/IP address when running `solr create`?

Comment: I'm using vagrant to automate the CKAN instance creation. And you? Could you please help me to solve my problem, that seems just about the same as yours? Obs.: I put my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76972745/connection-refused-when-running-solr-create-from-vagrant-provision-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the hostname used for the `bin/solr` script [through the `SOLR_HOST` environment variable](https://github.com/apache/solr/blob/a12aea9bf9750a2da7ca5e51c2e57b79356e6824/solr/bin/solr#L327):

```
export SOLR_HOST=<ip>
sudo -u solr /opt/solr/bin/solr create -c collection_name
```

Comment: I tried this before posting and it didn't work, but in hindsight it's because `SOLR_HOST` is not passed through to the sudo user. This appears to work, though `sudo -u solr SOLR_HOST=<ip> /opt/solr/bin/solr create -c collection_name`

Comment: I tried this with export and directly during the command call, but nothing worked. I tried many IP addresses as well. After try tons of things I also write [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76972745/connection-refused-when-running-solr-create-from-vagrant-provision-file) cound you guys help me?